# Каким образом можно добавить объекты классов из пакета javafx.geometry?

Tags: java, javafx

Как их визуализировать и возможно ли это вообще? Например Point2D, он ведь не расширяет Node, следовательно его нельзя поместить ни в один из контейнеров.

Comment: Ну вообще не все классы предназначены для того чтобы быть частью графического интерфейса (как-то отображаться в окне). Если не наследуется от Node - то скорее всего так и есть. Point2D - скорее всего просто какой-то служебный класс с двумя координатами (x, y).

Comment: В общем так и есть: это просто служебные классы. Т.е. Point2D - это просто класс, описывающий точку на плоскости, но не предназначенный для ее отображения на экране. Подобная ситуация и с другими классами этого пакета. Возможно, если бы вы сказали что конкретно вы хотите получить, можно было бы что-то посоветовать.

Comment: @insolortiredofthisdrama Я думал над тем, как можно отображать объемные фигуры в графическом интерфейсе, когда случайно увидел этот пакет, а там оказалось больше «фигур», в отличие от пакета shape(хотя, может я чего-то не знаю/понимаю), по сути мой вопрос ведет к вопросу «Как создать движок?», но я не ставлю целью создание движка.

Comment: О какой графике идет речь? 2D или 3D

Comment: @EvgeniyTkachenko 3D

Comment: Создавать 3D фигуры можно наследуя класс MeshView